# asp.net mvc calling child record in the Edit or Details View

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Does anyone have any links to examples I might reference in detail for calling related child records in the Edit or Details View from the index?

I have an index view of Forms and when i click details or edit I would like the child records in WorkflowEvents_View Model to be visible via a partial view.

**Models**

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated from a template.
//
//     Manual changes to this file may cause unexpected behavior in your application.
//     Manual changes to this file will be overwritten if the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace WebApplication5.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;

    public partial class PowerPlatformEntities : DbContext
    {
        public PowerPlatformEntities()
            : base("name=PowerPlatformEntities")
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
        }

        public virtual DbSet<ListValues> ListValues { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Forms> Forms { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Forms_View> Forms_View { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<WorkflowEvents_View> WorkflowEvents_View { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
namespace WebApplication5.Controllers
{
    public class FormsController : Controller
    {
        private PowerPlatformEntities db = new PowerPlatformEntities();


        // GET: Forms
        public ActionResult Index()
        {


            return View(db.Forms_View.OrderByDescending(Forms => Forms.Modified).Take(100).ToList());

        }


        // GET: WorkflowEvents_View
        public ActionResult WorkflowEvents_View(int? FormID)
        {
            //return View(db.WorkflowEvents_View.OrderByDescending(WorkflowEvents_View => WorkflowEvents_View.Created).Take(100).ToList());



          return PartialView("WorkflowEvents_View", db.Forms.Find(FormID));
        }




        // GET: Forms/Details/5
        public ActionResult Details(int? FormID)
        {

            //var viewModel = new PowerPlatformEntities();

            Trace.WriteLine("GET /Forms/Details/" + FormID);
            if (FormID == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }

            Forms form = db.Forms.Find(FormID);


            if (form == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(form);

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery onclick event to load the partial view using ('#divName').load() method.